# Firebase retrieves snapshot value as null

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use the `.once(` function in Firebase and am successfully retrieving the snapshot.key NAME of the directory. But this key has also a value.
When requesting snapshot.val() also gives out null despise it having a value.

The database looks like this:

```
    stages {
    stage1AVERYLONGHASH : "values i want to get"
    stage2AVERYLONGHASH : "values i want to get"
    }
```

My code

```
    var ref = "stage1AVERYLONGHASH";
    var branch = firebase.database().ref(ref).once('value').then(function(s){
    console.log(s.key); // GIVES THE CORRECT ANSWER
    console.log(s.val()); //GIVES null ... doesn't give me the "values i want.."
```

Am i doing it completely wrong?
I'm new to Firebase.
Please know that the database is structured like this intentionally.
I restricted read permission on "stages".
The game works as just requesting a hash from the database as a reference, to get contents.

Comment: are you sure your ref is correct? by the structure that you shown, i think the ref should be "/stages/stage1"

Comment: i didn't want anyone to query trough the stages because they must be hidden in the database. is this okay?

Comment: i have restricted permissions on /stages/

Comment: im not familiar with the database rules, but as far as i know, you need to set the ref to be at the stage1 node. by the looks of it, if there is no parent node above stages, the ref should be "/stages/stage1". then the read access on "/stages" should be configured by the rules.

Comment: but giving read access to stages would result in XSS being able to read the childs, i don't want anyone to know about the child nodes of /stages except they know the hash.

Comment: referencing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383168/firebase-limit-read-to-individual-children-but-not-to-parent i think you can set the read access on the parent to be false while allowing it on the child

Comment: i already set these rules in the console. thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you suppose to get the reference of the stage and then get the stage1 reference from him like :

.ref("stage").child("stage1")

I'm not sure about the actual syntax but I know that this is how I get my firebase data in android studio

Comment: thanks, yes the database is oddly structured because i need to protect the whole childs of "stage" i don't want anyone who doesnt know the key's of the childs to read them.

Comment: You shouldn't count of the child name as security measure , you should use firebase authentication system

Comment: the childs name is a very long hash, i want people to be able to play it without auth.

Comment: also i have yet not experimented with auth, it would worsen the situation as i am even failing to do this simple thing.

Comment: The best way for you to get started with firebase realtime database is with postman and just try accessing values with their full URL, you can get the full URL of each value in the firebase console